# CSS on mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I've finished my web page with its style sheet, not sure how it didn't work on phone browser because it work on laptop browser.
It worked when I put it on free web host and then open it with phone browser, but when I put it in phone storage, none of the CSS applied

moved the CSS file (prev href='folder/style.css') to href='style.css'
also use vendor prefix (-moz-,-webkit-,-ms-)

Answer (score -1):

simple solution of this problem,
first open file in laptop and inspect your website or page then use responsive button which look like mobile.

and your css isn't apply because some mobile phone features are not able to show website as like our laptop tablet or pc.

some have this type of feature like in MI mobile.

hope you understand...!

Comment: thx 4 the reply, yes i'm using xiaomi phone, weird thing is when the html and file located on phone storage and view them via laptop browser thw css still not loaded, i expect a work around this xiaomi bug